# Does endless While loop take up CPU resources?

Tags: c++, c, linux, infinite-loop, daemon

From what I understand, you write your Linux Daemon that listens to a request in an endless loop.
Something like..

```
int main() {
    while(1) {
        //do something...
    }
}
```

ref: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/c-daemon-process/

I read that sleeping a program makes it go into waiting mode so it doesn't eat up resources.

1.If I want my daemon to check for a request every 1 second, would the following be resource consuming?

```
int main() {
    while(1) {
        if (request) {
            //do something...
        }
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

2.If I were to remove the sleep, does it mean the CPU consumption will go up 100%?

3.Is it possible to run an endless loop without eating resources? Say..if it does nothing but just loops itself. Or just sleep(1).

Endless loops and CPU resources is a mystery to me.

Comment: Sleeping tells the scheduler to make some other process run on the CPU instead of your process for a specific unmount of time (too keep it simple). Your program won't consume any CPU resources while sleeping. Even sleeping for just some milliseconds makes things smooth in an endless loop like you've shown it.

Comment: If you are *listening* then you should use some multiplexing syscall like `poll(2)` (or the older, nearly obsolete, `select(2)`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **Is it possible to run an endless loop without eating resources? Say..if it does nothing but just loops itself. Or just sleep(1).**

There ia a better option.
You can just use a **semaphore**, which remains blocked at the begining of loop and you can signal the semaphore whenever you want the loop to execute.
Note that this will not eat any resources.

Comment: "will not eat any resources" is not exactly true... Creating a semaphore uses kernel resources and objects and is a fairly heavy operation. Waiting on the semaphore is a kernel-mode operation and will incur a context switch to kernel mode as well.

Comment: A semaphore would be appropriate if a timeout is used, but sleep is still probably best.  The semaphore is most relevant if you want your code to trigger on *either* timeout *or* some external event.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning semaphore. Gotta explore that when time comes :)

Answer (score 17):

The `poll` and `select` calls (mentioned by Basile Starynkevitch in a comment) or a semaphore (mentioned by Als in an answer) are the correct ways to wait for requests, depending on circumstances. On operating systems without `poll` or `select`, there should be something similar.

Neither `sleep`, `YieldProcessor`, nor `sched_yield` are proper ways to do this, for the following reasons.

`YieldProcessor` and `sched_yield` merely move the process to the end of the runnable queue but leave it runnable. The effect is that they allow other processes at the same or higher priority to execute, but, when those processes are done (or if there are none), then the process that called `YieldProcessor` or `sched_yield` continues to run. This causes two problems. One is that lower priority processes still will not run. Another is that this causes the processor to be always running, using energy. We would prefer the operating system to recognize when no process needs to be running and to put the processor into a low-power state.

`sleep` may permit this low-power state, but it plays a guessing game about how long it will be until the next request comes in, it wakes the processor repeatedly when there is no need, and it makes the process less responsive to requests, since the process will continue sleeping until the expiration of the requested time even if there is a request to be serviced.

The `poll` and `select` calls are designed for exactly this situation. They tell the operating system that this process wants to service a request coming in on one of its I/O channels but otherwise has no work to do. This allows the operating system to mark the process as not runnable and to put the processor in a low-power state if suitable.

Using a semaphore provides the same behavior, except that the signal to wake the process comes from another process raising the semaphore instead of activity arising in an I/O channel. Semaphores are suitable when the signal to do some work arrives in this way; simply use whichever of `poll` or a semaphore is more appropriate for your situation.

The criticism that `poll`, `select`, or a semaphore causes a kernel-mode call is irrelevant, because the other methods also cause kernel-mode calls. A process cannot sleep on its own; it has to call the operating system to request it. Similarly, `YieldProcessor` and `sched_yield` make requests to the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes -- removing sleep gives 100% CPU -- but the answer does depend on some additional details.  It consumes all CPU it can get, unless...

1. The loop body is trivial, and optimised away.
2. The loop contains a blocking operation (like a file or network operation). The link you provide suggests to avoid this, but it is often a good idea to block until something relevant happens.

**EDIT :** For your scenario, I support the suggestion made by @Als.

**EDIT 2:** I expect this answer has received a -1 because I claim blocking operations can actually be a good idea.  [If you -1, you should leave a motivation in a comment so that we all may learn something.]

Current popular thinking is that non-block (event-based) IO is good and blocking is bad.  This view is oversimplified because it assumes all software that performs IO can improve throughput by using non-blocking operations.

*What?*  Am I really suggesting that using non-blocking IO can actually reduce throughput?  Yes it can.  When a process serves a single activity it is actually better to use blocking IO because blocking IO only burns resources that have already been paid for in the existence of the process.

In contrast, non-blocking IO can carry a greater fixed overhead than simple blocking IO.  If the process isn't able to supply additional IO that can be interleaved, then there is nothing gained by paying for non-blocking setup.  (In practice, the greatest cost of innapropriate non-blocking IO is simply in the added code complexity.  Beyond that, this topic is largely a thought exercise.)

Under blocking IO we rely upon the operating system to schedule those processes that can make progress.  That's what the OS is designed to do.

Under non-blocking IO we have greater setup costs but can share the resources of the process and its threads between interleaved work.  The non-blocking IO is therefor ideal for any process that serves multiple independent activities, such as a web server.  The throughput gained is vastly superior to the fixed cost overheads of non-blocking IO.

Comment: Software may not improve throughput by using non-blocking I/O, but it always improves *responsiveness*.  Yes, you should block, but it should be a blocking call that waits for a variety of events, not a blocking I/O call that causes user inputs to be ignored until the I/O completes.  `select`, `poll`, `aio_suspend` are all examples.  You say "If the process isn't able to supply additional IO that can be interleaved", but there's always at least one additional input than can happen... a user request to quit.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's true. Interactive applications shouldn't block indefinitely, e.g. a semaphore should then use a timeout. That said, posix backend services can receive signals even when performing a blocking operation. All in all, you've raised a good point to remember - thanks.