# Execute QTimer just once and logic fails in while loop Qt

Tags: c++, qt

*OS: Linux

SDK : Qt

Widgets ->2  QLineEdits say( lEditSndRequest) & lEditGetResponse in mainQwidget window*

*QTCPSocketClient implementation as a child of mainQwidget window.*

*Overview :*
  User send request to serverMachine and get response. The request first get displayed in lEditSndRequest. The lEditSndRequest forward that request to Client part where it write to Server using Qt libraries.All work fine.
 Server also send response to client. It goes to client part say in func getResponseFrmMachine. The signal emitted from that function  that updates lEditGetResponse. when it updates LEditGetResponse textChangeSignal is emitted when calls slot say getCliRespTextChanged().
This slot updates another membervaribale "isMachineStarted" to true or false.

Say if we receive response from machine like "machine_started" it will update bool member variable to true.

*Issue:*

User send command like "make_machine_move" . But Before by client code can send that command to server , I need to send command like "start_machine_first" . I use vector to store both commands

Alos I have a function say returnFrontFrmVec(); Which returns first element from vector and then erase it from vec.
 I pass that vector in a function which actually writes to server. its there my logic fails.
What I want is  if vector size > 1 ( it means to has 2 commands) then extract front part and comapre with "machine_started". if true then send machine_started command and wait for response before executing another command. The machine may take upto 2 mins to start. so either if timer expires( in that case clear vector as machine has not started and there is no use to send move command ) OR wait till we receive reponse. The response as mentioned earlier goes to lEditGetRespone and slot there will update bool varibale  "isMachineStarted" to true. So I am checking against it.

*output*
Server does not get message , and connectedToMachine( ) slot is never called & application stuck in While loop.

```
void prepareWriteToMachine()
{
  int sizeOfVec = noOfElemInVecCmd();

  if( sizeOfVec  == 1 ) // there are no other command so just execute teh first command from vector
    {
      QString strTemp = returnFrontFrmVec();
      // place temp str in storeLineEditMsg to be used by connectedtoMachine
      setStoreMsgFrmCliReq( strTemp );
      reconnectToServer(); // this will emit SIGNAL connected() which inturn calls slot connectedToMachine( ) 
    }
  if( sizeOfVec > 1 )
    {
      QString strTemp = returnFrontFrmVec();
      if( strTemp == CMD_STRT)// send it and wait for response
        {
          setStoreMsgFrmCliReq( strTemp );
          reconnectToServer();// this will emit SIGNAL connected() which inturn calls slot connectedToMachine( ) // But nver get called
        }
      // Now check if Machine has started we will get response in MainWindow and
      // it will update isMachineStarted so we can check that
      QTimer *timer ;
      timerStart( timer, TIMEOUT_START );
      while( isMachineStarted() == false  )  // getMachineRunning-> return isMachineStarted ??
        {
          // do nothing wiat for machine to send machine_started
        }
      if( isMachineStarted() == true )
        {
          // if we are here it mean timer has not expired & machine is runing
          // now check for another command and execute
          timerStop( timer );
          while( vecCmd.size() > 0 )
            {
              QString strTemp = returnFrontFrmVec();
              setStoreMsgFrmCliReq( strTemp );
              reconnectToServer();
            }
        }
    }
}


void connectedToMachine( )  
{
  // if we reach here then client is connected to server ..
  //send signal to update connecting status in Qlineedit


  QByteArray block;
  QDataStream out( &block, QIODevice::WriteOnly );

  out.setVersion( QDataStream::Qt_4_3 );
  out << quint16( 0 ) << getStoreMsgFrmCliReq();
  out.device()->seek( 0 );
  out << quint16( block.size() - sizeof( quint16 ) );

  sockForMachine->write( block );
  //reset storeLineEditMessage
  storeLineEditMsg.clear();
}

void timerStart( QTimer* timer, int timeMillisecond )
{
  timer = new QTimer( this );
  connect( timer, SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( noRespFrmMachine( ) ) ) ;
  timer->start( timeMillisecond );
}

void timerStop( QTimer* timer )
{
  if( timer )
    {
      timer->stop();
    }
}

void noRespFrmMachine( )
{
  vecCmd.clear();
}

QString returnFrontFrmVec( )
{
  QString frntCmd;
  if( ! vecCmd.empty() )
    {
      frntCmd = vecCmd.front();
      vecCmd.erase( vecCmd.begin() );// retrieve and now delete first element
    }
  return frntCmd;
}

bool isMachineStarted()( )const
{

  return isMachineStarted;
}
void setMachineStarted( bool isRun )
{

isMachineStarted = isRun;
}
```

Comment: QTimers will fire on the same event loop of the thread they are created in.  You are sticking your code in a loop in your while statement, which is bad because you don't have any pauses in there.  Your while loop never gives up the CPU and I would guess if you ran a top command you'd see your app sitting at 100%.

Even if the timer fired, it would never get allowed to run because your while loop implementation doesn't allow it.

Comment: @ChaseHenslee Thanks mate. BUt my issue is just above where I haev called QTimer  there is a function call reconnectToServer() this function emit connected() signal and ConnectedToMachine Slot executed. but before it can call that slot it goes into while loop. why is that? I mean technically it shoudl call connectedToMachine first and tehn while loop right?

Comment: I don't see where you have your connection to the "connectedToMachine" slot, but if they are in different threads then the default connection call will use Qt:QueuedConnection.  Meaning it won't fire until it gets to it on the Event Loop.  

It's hard to tell without seeing the code for connectToServer, or the call that sets up the signal/slot connection.

Comment: Actually it goes into connectedToMachine slot and and writes start command to send it to machine. But machine nver gets it. If I comment out while loop then atleast that start command goes to machine and I receive proper response from machine

Comment: So that's telling me that my theory is correct.  The reason the while loop breaks you is because your slot is being called from the Event Loop queue on the same thread.  Also, what you are trying to do is actually a state machine.  You should consider implementing this logic using QStateMachine instead.  You could have a non-connected state, and transition to a connected state that way.  Good luck man.

Comment: Thanks Chase for the help. I didnt get what you mean by state machine and  QState Machine? Can you point me to some tutorial or sample code

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstatemachine.html  gives a good description of how to use the state machine.  Essentially you use Qt Signals to transition between states.  So your logic that sends a signal to the "connectedToMachine" slot could actually be a state instead.  Then instead of sitting in a while loop, you can trigger when the state changes to fire the next event.  

Granted, most of the examples you find will be used for GUIs, the same principle can be used for non-guis as well.

Comment: cool . thanks a lot . Just last question how did you find tout hat while loop will consume all resources? I mean in many programs people have used while loop that do nothing  and they never run into problem. I am asking because it will help to learn it and I recognise it in future

Comment: It's because your looping without a pause in the loop.  Certain functions can release the CPU and allow other processes to run.  sleep, wait, mutex locking, semaphones, and select calls are some examples of methods that would release the CPU.  Your while loop doesn't wait for anything.  It just checks the variable, goes back to the while loop, checks again, forever.   In a single threaded environment, no other code could ever run.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680512/does-endless-while-loop-take-up-cpu-resources  some good responses in there.